# How to insert html tags when setting React component's innerText dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Suppose I have the following code:

```
const text = "This is a piece of text with a <a>link</a>";

const Comp = () => {
  return <div>{text}</div>;
};
```

On the resulting page, I see the literal text "This is a piece of text with a <a>link</a>". How to convert the word "link" into an actual `<a>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to use it.

Check below snippet.

```js
function createMarkup() {
  const text = "This is a piece of text with a <a>link</a>";
  return {__html: text};
}

function setHtml() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}

const Comp = () => {
  return <div>{setHtml()}</div>;
};
```